# Questions Tags Users Unanswered shifting specific column to before/after specific column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

In dataframe example :

```
  medcine_preg_oth medcine_preg_oth1 medcine_preg_oth2 medcine_preg_oth3
0          Berplex           Berplex              None              None
1              NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
2              NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
3            obmin             obmin              None              None
4              NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
```

'medcine_preg_oth1' 'medcine_preg_oth2' 'medcine_preg_oth3' ,these three columns are in somewhere of dataframe with other columns. . I want to shift these three : medcine_preg_oth1 medcine_preg_oth2 medcine_preg_oth3 to the place of after 'medcine_preg_oth'.

My idea is shifting the specific columns to place after/ before specific columns in dataframe for wider purpose . please suggest me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can re-arrange your columns like this:

```
re_ordered_columns = ['medicine_pred_oth','medcine_preg_oth1','medcine_preg_oth2','medcine_preg_oth3']
df = df[re_ordered_columns+df.columns.difference(re_ordered_columns).tolist()]
```

add the remaining columns in place of `...`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , but there are 699 column , included of these four column . So it would take time too!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Still erro :KeyError: "['medicine_pred_oth'] not in index"

Comment: Don't add the list as a string. It should work then

Comment: Hi , I got the answer ,                                    
x=df.columns.get_loc('time_use_4') # getting colum index , the place after that column 

var_list=new_var # this list are for column list that are needed to move 
new_position = x
for var in var_list:
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    column_to_move = var
    new_position += 1
    cols.insert(new_position, cols.pop(cols.index(column_to_move)))
    df = df[cols]